# How to detect the custom shape in the given binary image using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am looking for a way to **detect custom shape** in the given binary image using **OpenCV**.

my custom shape is like below:

[image]

I am trying to find if the above shape(or approx. to it) exists in the given 512 by 512 binary image.

I tried different ways like using **cv::matchTemplate()**
but this is not working for variant with **scaled and rotated shapes**.

**I need some solution to identify the these kind of shapes in a given binary images.**

**Thank in advance**

**some information on shape**
:shapes is simple with three connected component with line separation.
These are shapes of cross section of tibia, fibula and talus bone at ankle joint.
some more images of shape

[image]

**Edit:**
512by512 Images having the the shape
[image]

[image]

512 by 512 image without the shape
[image]

Comment: top and bottom row images are mirrored objects? The big "hole" between center and outer object ins once on the left and once on the right?!? Can you define how the object looks like, because in some way they dont look similar. How dissimilar to other structures in the images are they? I would use clustering of close binary regions + cv::minAreaRect + size/rotation-normalization + chamfer matching on the normalized regions.

Comment: Actually i tried to create Haar cascade classifier(HCC) for detection of this shape. For that I did some research and understood that I need lots of positive and negative data for training of HCC.
So I collected some images of that shapes and tried to make them rotate/mirror and create more positive data(which is data augmentation) for training purpose
But when I tested Hcc for testing data it go failed for negative scenarios(HCC is detecting shape even though it is not present)

Comment: generally as i mentioned the shapes is just image of bones in CT scan.(you can see it here https://www.google.com/search?q=ankle+joint+line+in+CT+Scan+axial+view&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjC_pfs9e_1AhVmyHMBHYyjBBQQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=ankle+joint+line+in+CT+Scan+axial+view&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DMBFjjFGCdFmgAcAB4AIAB7QGIAYQPkgEGMC4xMC4ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=8UgCYoLCGuaQz7sPjMeSoAE&bih=697&biw=1364&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN934IN934#imgrc=tanHDp2BqXxHWM) generally each white region is one separate bone(tibia, fibula and talus) that is segregated by the thin black region(or line).

Comment: cascade classifier might also have problems with rotation and I guess it's not so great for binary images. If you really want to use an expensive detector, try deep neural networks like YOLO. If you really want to continue with cascade classifier, use as many negative images as possible and tune training parameters so reduce the number of false positives. Training will take ages so that enough additional false samples can be found in later stages (2-3 weeks of training time are typical for a real use case and enough images).

Comment: yeah Cascade classifier didn't helped me much. I am open to any method to use to detect that shape. And regarding the binary images, Actual available CT scans are in Greyscale image, I just converted them to binary in hope that it can help in some way for cascade training.   **Please suggest any suitable method. it will be very helpful to me.**

Comment: I would still use clustering + size/rotation-normalization + chamfer-matching, but it would be necessary to rate similarity/dissimilarity to other bones. Can you provide a few binarized full size images with/without that specific bone shape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241819/discussion-between-v01-and-micka).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my algorithm. The idea is to cluster contours (in the sample algorithm just by dilation/erosion) and for each contour to normalize the size and to test the shape similarity in different rotations. Then compare the image region with the template.

I am using this image as template:

[image] with this contour [image]

and this object image (removed the white background because I assume to use external contours only.

[image]

The algorithm gives this result:

```
found target shape with similarity 72.5144% and angle: 180 degrees
5 of 26
found target shape with similarity 73.1325% and angle: 0 degrees
6 of 26
found target shape with similarity 71.7287% and angle: 270 degrees
7 of 26
8 of 26
found target shape with similarity 72.3608% and angle: 90 degrees
9 of 26
10 of 26
11 of 26
12 of 26
13 of 26
14 of 26
15 of 26
16 of 26
found target shape with similarity 62.7371% and angle: 60 degrees
17 of 26
found target shape with similarity 62.6041% and angle: 240 degrees
18 of 26
19 of 26
20 of 26
found target shape with similarity 62.8935% and angle: 150 degrees
21 of 26
found target shape with similarity 62.39% and angle: 330 degrees
22 of 26
23 of 26
24 of 26
25 of 26
```

[image]

This is the code (with some dirty helpers for saving the images etc.):

```
int glob_counter = 0;
double contourMaskSimilarity(float angleDiff, float scale, cv::Point2f cont_center, std::vector<cv::Point> contour, cv::Mat img, cv::Point2f template_center, cv::Mat img_templ)
{
    cv::Mat rotationMat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(cont_center, angleDiff, scale);
    cv::Mat rotationMatPersp = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
    for (int y = 0; y < rotationMat.rows; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < rotationMat.cols; ++x)
        {
            rotationMatPersp.at<double>(y, x) = rotationMat.at<double>(y, x);
        }

    //cv::Mat img_tmp = img_color.clone();
    cv::Mat img_tmp_mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
    std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point> >contours_img;
    contours_img.push_back(contour);
    cv::drawContours(img_tmp_mask, contours_img, 0, cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);

    //cv::circle(img_tmp, cont_center, 3, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2); // drawing

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> warpedPoints;
    points.push_back(cont_center);

    cv::perspectiveTransform(points, warpedPoints, rotationMatPersp);

    cv::Mat translation = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
    translation.at<double>(0, 2) = template_center.x - warpedPoints[0].x; // x
    translation.at<double>(1, 2) = template_center.y - warpedPoints[0].y; // x

    cv::Mat transformation = translation * rotationMatPersp; // transformation after each other => 1. rotation 2. translation

    cv::Mat imgBin = img.clone();
    imgBin = imgBin & img_tmp_mask;
    cv::Mat imgBinWarped;
    // warp the image to same size and rotation as the template, according to angle and center
    //cv::warpPerspective(imgBin, imgBinWarped, transformation, cv::Size(img.size().width * scale, img.size().height * scale));
    cv::warpPerspective(imgBin, imgBinWarped, transformation, img_templ.size());

    cv::Rect subImage = cv::Rect(0, 0, img_templ.cols, img_templ.rows);
    cv::Mat imgSub = imgBinWarped(subImage);

    cv::Mat imgMul = imgSub.mul(img_templ); // 255 everywhere where template and current image-region are non-zero. 0 everywhere else

    double sum1 = cv::countNonZero(imgMul);
    double sum2 = cv::countNonZero(img_templ);
    double sum3 = cv::countNonZero(imgSub);
    //std::cout << sum1 << " " << sum2 << " " << sum3 << std::endl;

    // confidence similar to intersection over union.
    // use a better shape-similarity here, like a chamfer matching or a mean-hausdorff-distance?
    double conf = sum1 * sum1 / (sum2 * sum3);
    //std::cout << conf * 100 << " %" << std::endl;

    // TODO: remove!
    if (conf > 0.5)
    {
        cv::imwrite("C:/data/StackOverflow/bone_shapes/out_sub_" + std::to_string(glob_counter) + "_" + std::to_string(conf) + ".png", imgSub);
        cv::imwrite("C:/data/StackOverflow/bone_shapes/out_mul_" + std::to_string(glob_counter) + "_" + std::to_string(conf) + ".png", imgMul);
        glob_counter++;
    }

    return conf;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img_templ = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/bone_shapes/bone_shape_template.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    // binarize the img (I guess it was binarized already?)
    cv::Mat templ = img_templ > 0;

    cv::Mat img_shapes = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/bone_shapes/bones_set_blackBG.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    // binarize the image (it was some grayscale gradients at the object borders...)
    cv::Mat img = img_shapes > 200;

    // 1. close-operator to merge all the parts of the shapes to a single contour. For other shapes you might need some kind of clustering.
    cv::Mat img_closed = img.clone();
    int nDilations = 2;
    cv::dilate(img_closed, img_closed, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MorphShapes::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3), cv::Point(1, 1)), cv::Point(1, 1), nDilations);
    cv::erode(img_closed, img_closed, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MorphShapes::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3), cv::Point(1, 1)), cv::Point(1, 1), nDilations);

    cv::Mat template_closed = templ.clone();
    int nDilationsTemplate = 2;
    cv::dilate(template_closed, template_closed, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MorphShapes::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3), cv::Point(1, 1)), cv::Point(1, 1), nDilations);
    cv::erode(template_closed, template_closed, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MorphShapes::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3), cv::Point(1, 1)), cv::Point(1, 1), nDilations);

    // 2. find contours (only necessary once for the template:)

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contour_template;
    cv::findContours(template_closed, contour_template, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours_img;
    cv::findContours(img_closed, contours_img, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


    // display the results for debugging/sanity checks only
    cv::Mat img_color, template_color;
    cv::cvtColor(img_shapes, img_color, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    cv::cvtColor(img_templ, template_color, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    for (int i = 0; i < contour_template.size(); ++i)
        cv::drawContours(template_color, contour_template, i, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4);
    cv::imshow("template color", template_color);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours_img.size(); ++i)
        cv::drawContours(img_color, contours_img, i, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    cv::imshow("img color", img_color);
    //cv::waitKey(1);


    // make sure the template only has one contour!
    if (contour_template.size() != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "closed template doesnt consist of a single contour" << std::endl;
        throw("closed template doesnt consist of a single contour");
    }

    // 3. get size and orientation of the shapes:
    cv::RotatedRect template_orientation = cv::minAreaRect(contour_template[0]);
    cv::Point2f template_center;    float template_size = 0;
    //cv::minEnclosingCircle(contour_template[0], template_center, template_size);
    template_center = template_orientation.center;
    template_size = (template_orientation.size.width > template_orientation.size.height) ? template_orientation.size.width : template_orientation.size.height;

    // now check every contour in the target image:
    for (int i = 0; i < contours_img.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " of " << contours_img.size() << std::endl;
        std::vector<cv::Point> cont = contours_img[i];

        cv::RotatedRect cont_orientation = cv::minAreaRect(cont);
        cv::Point2f cont_center;    float cont_size = 0;

        cont_center = cont_orientation.center;
        cont_size = (cont_orientation.size.width > cont_orientation.size.height) ? cont_orientation.size.width : cont_orientation.size.height;
        // angle difference according to rotated rectangle bounding boxes
        float angleDiff = template_orientation.angle - cont_orientation.angle;
        // scale according to rotated rectangle bounding boxes
        float scale = template_size / cont_size;

        double bestSimilarity = 0.0;
        float bestAngle = 0.0;
        float stepDegree = 15; // make smaller if you need a finer rotation resolution.

        // check various angles:
        for (float j = 0; j < 360.0f; j+=stepDegree)
        {
            //float angle = angleDiff + j * stepDegree; // initial guess for rotation. Works if shape is really similar
            float angle = j;
            // similarity computation is slow for small contours. Maybe because of the warping?
            double similarity = contourMaskSimilarity(angle, scale, cont_center, contours_img[i], img, template_center, templ);
            if (similarity > bestSimilarity)
            {
                bestSimilarity = similarity;
                bestAngle = angle;
            }
        }
        glob_counter++;

        if (bestSimilarity > 0.5)
        {
            cv::drawContours(img_color, contours_img, i, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            std::cout << "found target shape with similarity " << 100*bestSimilarity << "% and angle: " << bestAngle << " degrees"<< std::endl;
        }

        //cv::waitKey(0);
    
        //cv::waitKey(0);
        /*
        std::cout << rotationMat << std::endl;

        cv::Point2f offsetTemplateImage;
        offsetTemplateImage.x = -template_center.x;
        offsetTemplateImage.y = -template_center.y;
        cv::Rect subImage = cv::Rect(cont_center.x + offsetTemplateImage.x, cont_center.y + offsetTemplateImage.y, img_templ.cols, img_templ.rows);
        */
    }

    cv::imshow("template", img_templ);
    cv::imshow("template binary", templ);
    cv::imshow("template closed", template_closed);

    cv::imshow("shapes", img_shapes);
    cv::imshow("shapes binary", img);
    cv::imshow("shapes closed", img_closed);

    cv::imshow("result", img_color);

    cv::imwrite("C:/data/StackOverflow/bone_shapes/out_template_color.png", template_color);
    cv::imwrite("C:/data/StackOverflow/bone_shapes/out_result.png", img_color);


    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Here are some samples for warped images and the multiplied binary with the template:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the code work @Micka. I am actually new to image processing and opencv. I will try the given code and let you know my thoughts. I was actually collecting images that you have asked for in the question chat. **I have added some images in question. please check.**

Comment: Already tested them. The algorithm detects both correct/positive bones and doesnt detect the negative bone (nice) but also detects additional bones in both positive images (not good). So the shape size/rotation part looks ok, but the matching part isnt sophisticated enough yet.

Comment: Hi @Micka, Seems like it is working, but not in all kind of scenarios. But its fine as of now. Thank you very much for the support

Comment: @V01 thank you for the bounty. I would like to improve the similarity value computation step (which is quite primitive atm), by using more shape properties (currently it is more about area). Unfortunately I dont have much time at the moment, because of project deadlines.